# How to stop setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I want to use setInterval to continually check a div's position and trigger an event just once.

Basically, I'm creating a very simple game - I have a `sheep` div that can be moved left and right on the page. I want to trigger an event once `sheep` reaches a certain point.

I"m using setInterval to check where the sheep is every 200milliseconds - if it is past 100px it creates an alert with the position. The problem is that setInterval continues to trigger the alert every 200milliseconds, whereas I only want it to happen once.

```
    var positionInterval = setInterval(function(){
        var sheepPosition = sheep.position();
            if (sheepPosition.left > 100) {
                alert(sheepPosition.left);
                sheepPosition = 0;
            }
    },200);
```

I thought that by including `sheepPosition = 0` at the end of the IF function would stop it from repeating, but i realise that this won't work because that is only modifying the variable inside the IF function, and every time a new interval begins `sheepPosition`'s value is taken from `sheep.position`.

So how can I stop setInterval from repeating more than once?

I also tried using  a variable counter and `clearInterval`:

```
var intervalCounter = 0;

var positionInterval = setInterval(function(){
        var sheepPosition = sheep.position();
            if (sheepPosition.left > 100) {
                alert(sheepPosition.left);
                intervalCounter = 1;
            }
    },200);

setInterval(function(){
        if (intervalCounter === 1) {
           positionInterval.clearInterval;
        }
    },200);
```

but this didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe the syntax is `clearInterval(positionInterval)`. If you're making a game, you should look up `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: [There's plenty of documentation about basic JavaScript available on the Internet.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

Comment: Your question is misleading. You ask how you can stop `setInterval` from repeating more than once, yet it's clear from your code that you need it to repeat more than once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to set another interval to check your first interval. You can do it directly from within the `positionInterval`.
So:

```
var positionInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var sheepPosition = sheep.position();
        if (sheepPosition.left > 100) {
            alert(sheepPosition.left);
            clearInterval(positionInterval);
        }
}, 200);
```

Comment: Really? What does `this` refer to inside the function?

Comment: You're right. I have corrected it in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use following

```
clearInterval(positionInterval);
```